# How to draw matrices with lines and side braces?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays, underbrace, overbrace

I want to generate something like in the figure below. I have currently the following but is not complete as you can observe. Any idea how to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \overbrace{
    \mleft[
    \begin{array}
        \mat{A}_1 \mid \mat{A}_2
    \end{array}
    \mright]}_{\mat{A}}
    \overbrace{
    \mleft[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
        \mat{S}_1 & \mat{S}_2 \\ 
        \hline
        \mat{S}_3 & \mat{S}_4 
    \end{array}
    \mright]}_{\mat{S}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly you want to use `nicematrix`. https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put braces over certain parts of matrices?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639234/how-to-put-braces-over-certain-parts-of-matrices) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582459/tikz-matrix-with-array-below-and-braces/582476#582476)

Comment: @WillieWong Can you give an example with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fine tuning may be required, and you should absolutely read the documentation for `nicematrix`. But here is an example of the second matrix that you posted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[ 
        \begin{bNiceArray}[last-col,margin]{w{c}{7em}|w{c}{3.5em}}
                \\
                (\mathbf{G}+\mathbf{R})\mathbf{U} & \mathbf{R}\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{C}  & \hspace*{8pt} m_1 \\
                \\
                \hline
                \Block{5-1}{\mathbf{U}} \\
                \\
                                                  & \mathbf{P} & \hspace*{8pt} m_2\\
                                                  \\
                &
                \CodeAfter
                \UnderBrace[yshift=5pt]{1-1}{8-1}{m_2}
                \UnderBrace[yshift=5pt]{1-2}{8-2}{m_1}
                \SubMatrix.{1-1}{3-2}\}[right-xshift=8pt]
                \SubMatrix.{4-1}{8-2}\}[right-xshift=8pt]
        \end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Quick explanations:

- `bNiceArray` specifies that you want to put it in brackets. using the `...Array` version as opposed to the `...Matrix` version gives you more control on the column specifications (which we use).
- `last-col` allows you to add one final column *outside* the brackets. (Where we put the `m_1` and `m_2`.)
- `margin` puts a bit of margin, otherwise the `\hline` runs up against the brackets.
- The column specifier `w{c}{7em}` puts in a fixed width column with width 7em and contents centered.

  - You can alternatively use some empty columns to get the horizontal spacing; I choose this to require less typing/counting.
- Note that the last column is *not* included in the column specification.
- Blank rows are included for vertical spacing.
- Extra spaces are inserted ahead of `m_1` and `m_2` to accommodate the braces (to be put in later in the `\SubMatrix` block).
- `\CodeAfter` allows you to mark up the matrix additionally.

  - Use `\SubMatrix` to put extra delimters, such as vertical braces (read the documentation for syntax); the extra `xshift` is to push the braces beyond the brackets; this is why we have to add space in front of the `m_1` and `m_2`.
  - Use `\UnderBrace` to put horizontal braces across columns. Read the documentation for syntax. I put in an extra `yshift` to make it more closely resemble the spacing you have in your question.

Comment: Thanks for it. One question though. I checked the documentation but I do not see how to add braces on the left size instead. So Imagine $m_1$ and $m_2$ braces being at the left (at the beginning) instead of right (at the end) as it is now. How does one do that?

Comment: Use `\SubMatrix`. The first argument is the delimiter on the left of the submatrix. In the above example I specified `.` for the "null delimiter".